# Getting "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" for jQuery files included in Wordpress as well as the CDN

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Firebug was giving me the `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` error for the jQuery-Migrate file included with the latest version of Wordpress.

original HTML:

`<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.potgieter.nl/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1"></script>`

Error:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
})( jQuery, window );'
```

After looking around on SO and other sites, I found several people suggesting to use the jQuery CDN at http://code.jquery.com/ By the looks of it their version is newer, but I figured the worst case scenario that would give a new error.

I grabbed their code and used that instead, but I'm still getting this error.

new HTML

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js"
 integrity="sha256-lsVOB+3Yhm6He5MkTO3Bw/Xw4NXK7wYYTi1Y+M/2PrM="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

same error

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
})( jQuery, window );
```

What's going on here? I can't imagine there's a bug in the official CDN, and I'd image that the files included in Wordpress should not be bugged either, so what am I missing here?

Edit: image for context https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhUjl.jpg[image]

Comment: is jQuery.js loading before that script?

Comment: It's loading directly after this script. Should that be the other way around?

Comment: Jquery should loaded first and then jquery migrate.

Comment: yes... that's where `jQuery` gets defined

Comment: That actually makes a whole lot of sense. I tried this, and the issue has been resolved. Boy do I feel like an idiot.

Comment: @charlietfl You solved my issue, but I can't accept a comment for an answer. If you come back to answer, I'll accept it and you can get the rep you deserve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.js needs to be loaded before any other jQuery migrate, because that's where jQuery gets defined. If jQuery isn't defined, the system won't know what to do with jQuery migrate, and it won't work.

Comment: Note:

@charlietfl answered this in the comments, but not as an answer. This question has been open for 2 weeks now, so I'm making this a community wiki and closing the question by answering it myself, as per meta answer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/5872029